# Codeigniter failed to load error 404

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Can't load css files getting error 404 using codeigniter.

here is my link tag

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">

<head>
```

server folders

```
-httpdocs
---application
---cgi-bin
---css --> style.css
---system
---user_guide
```

error

```
GET http://31.8.7.79/css/style.css
```

Im not sure if it could be a problem but for some reason codeigniter uses this http adress http://31.8.7.79/ instead of http://www.someurl.com could it be because of Apache Server?

Tried to do same exact thing with different server without Apache Server and it works perfectly

Comment: You must set your base url in config.php else links won't work properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file `application/config/config.php` set the base_url item as follows and see if that helps

```
$config['base_url']  = 'http://www.someurl.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Config.php**

```
$config['base_url']  = 'http://www.someurl.com/';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|(.*)\.css|(.*)\.js|(.*)\.jpg|(.*)\.jpeg|(.*)\.png|(.*)\.bmp|(.*)\.gif|(.*)\.doc|(.*)\.shtml|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```